# Loss of Photo Rotation

Tags: photos

All of a sudden I am unable to view my pictures if I turn my phone sideways.  Can someone let me know what I may have done wrong and how to correct it??

Comment: When you say "unable to view my pictures if I turn my phone sideways", do you mean that the pictures disappear leaving a blank screen, or do you mean that you can in fact still view them but they don't rotate? And if it's the latter option, do other things rotate, like Safari?

Comment: I can see everything but none of the other apps I have, Safari, Scrabble, Candy Crush, etc rotate when I turn my phone.

Comment: Could you explain the steps that it would take to replicate, or if you are unaware of the steps, would you be willing to post screenshots and anything else that seems somewhat relevant?

Comment: Have you just set the rotation lock?

Comment: Please, I am not as dumb as I am going to sound but I have never had this happen before so I cannot honestly say that I have noticed where I would check if I accidently put the rotation lock on.....  Can you let me know where I should be looking for it????

Comment: You can take a screenshot by simultaneously pressing the home and sleep buttons. That would tell us if rotation lock is on. Rotation lock is most easily accessed by swiping up from the bottom of the screen to open Control Center.

Comment: @MikeScott Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled rotation lock? You can check by swiping up from the bottom of the screen to open the Control Centre and then checking the right-hand of the five icons at the top.